# Temporary table in PostgreSQL

Tags: function, postgresql, temporary

I am trying to create temporary table in my function in postgreSQL. But getting an syntax error. The details as show below in example:

Example:

```
Create or replace function testing(a varchar(100),b varchar(100))
returns setof record as
$$
Declare
      create temp table testtable(x int, y int identity(1,1), z varchar(100));
....
```

Error: Syntax error at or near "table".

Comment: You can only `declare` variables. The `CREATE TABLE` (ddl) statement can only be run between the `BEGIN` - `END` blocks.

Comment: @pozs, Oops! Sorry for that. I got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @pozs Add that as an answer to be accepted by Meem so it does not stay answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only [`DECLARE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-declarations.html) variables.

The `CREATE TABLE` (ddl) statement can only be run between the `BEGIN` - `END` blocks.