# Temporary table postgresql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I can't find a clear explanation of the syntax to create (and use) tables just for the inside calculations of a function. Could anyone give me a syntax exemple please ?

From what I've found, I have tried this (with and without `@` before `temp_table`) :

```
CREATE FUNCTION test.myfunction()
RETURNS SETOF test.out_table
AS $$

DECLARE @temp_table TABLE
( 
        id int,
        value text
 )
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO @temp_table 
        SELECT id, value
        FROM test.another_table;

 INSERT INTO test.out_table
        SELECT id, value
        FROM @temp_table;
RETURN END
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

I get :

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DECLARE"
>      LINE 5:  DECLARE @temp_table TABLE

-

I also tried the CREATE TABLE approach suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23654146/4348534), this way :

```
CREATE FUNCTION test.myfunction()
RETURNS SETOF test.out_table
AS $$

    CREATE TABLE temp_table AS
        SELECT id, value
        FROM test.another_table;

    INSERT INTO test.out_table
        SELECT id, value
        FROM temp_table;

$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

And I get this :

> ERROR:  relation "temp_table " does not exist
>        LINE 11:   FROM temp_table

(Obviously, I'm aware the temp_table is not necessary for what I'm doing in the code above, but that's not the point :) => I want to understand the syntax to get it to work)

Comment: Postgres uses temporary tables for this purpose.  Table variables are a feature of SQL Server.

Comment: Where in the manual did you find the syntax `DECLARE @temp_table TABLE...`?

Answer (score 27):

The appropriate syntax for creating a temp table is

```
create temp table...
```

but you have to be sure to drop the temp table before existing out of the function. Also, I'd suggest this syntax instead:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table AS
    SELECT id, value
    FROM test.another_table;
```

Thus your function will be like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test.myfunction()
RETURNS SETOF test.out_table
AS $$

    CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table AS
        SELECT id, value
        FROM test.another_table;

    INSERT INTO test.out_table
        SELECT id, value
        FROM temp_table;

DROP TABLE temp_table;

$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

But if I can be so kind, I'd like to rewrite this function so it is more correct:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test.myfunction()
RETURNS TABLE (id int, value varchar) -- change your datatype as needed
AS $$
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table AS
    SELECT id, value
    FROM test.another_table;

INSERT INTO test.out_table
    SELECT id, value
    FROM temp_table;

DROP TABLE temp_table;

RETURN QUERY 
SELECT id, value
from temp_table;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Untested; let me know if this fails.

Comment: I'll test it at work tomorrow and will let you know (and accept it if it works), in the meantime, I just wanted to thank you for taking the time :)

Comment: I get a syntax error because of the `CREATE` statement. More precisely, I get the following : `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "create"` // 
`LINE 4: create TEMP TABLE temp_mag_ref_compl AS` // 

`********** Erreur **********` // 

`ERROR: syntax error at or near "create"` // 
`État SQL :42601` // 
`Caractère : 114`

Comment: yeah, you are right. I changed it to add "begin;" and "end;" That should prevent the syntax error.

Comment: Oh god, I did try adding `BEGIN` and `END`... but not `BEGIN;` and `END;` (with semi-colons `;`)... Anyway,  I went with a totally different solution, so a working solution probably won't be of any use to me now (at least at the moment), but I'll still try to take some time (tomorrow at work) to try it out and give feedback. Anyway, thanks for the effort. Also, I suggested an edit.

Comment: Why do you say to be sure to drop the temp table before exiting the function?  Is there any mention of this in the docs?  What happens if you don't?

Comment: @Wildcard If you keep the transactions open, the temp table can persist, throwing a "table already exists" error.

Comment: @dizzystar You appear to be dropping the temporary table and then after that selecting it for the RETURN QUERY ... is that correct, wouldn't it not exist?

Comment: I get `ERROR:  CREATE TABLE AS is not allowed in a non-volatile function`