# how to select a column with more than one values from non-existing table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

How to select more than one value from a 'non-existing' table.

For example:

```
SELECT ('val1', 'val2') as "test"
```

[image]

How to make a column "test" with two values/rows val1 and val2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To temporarily generate rows with values, PostgreSQL has following options:

1. [`VALUES` Lists](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/queries-values.html) like `VALUES (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three');`
2. [`WITH` Queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/queries-with.html) (Common Table Expressions) common-table-expression
3. [`CREATE TABLE TEMPORARY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-TEMPORARY) to create a table for temporary use in this session

For small numbers of rows I would suggest the `VALUES` expression.
For more rows and usage in complex queries I would suggest the temporary table.

See also:

- [Temporary table postgresql function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091047/temporary-table-postgresql-function)
- [A Step-by-Step Guide To PostgreSQL Temporary Table](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-temporary-table/)
- [PostgreSQL Common Table Expressions vs a temporary table? - Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78253/postgresql-common-table-expressions-vs-a-temporary-table)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `union` two rows in table like below code:

```
select 'val1' as "test"
union
select 'val2' as "test"
```

[image]

Comment: that's nice, but what if I want to select 100 values?

Comment: It depends on your data format and your database version. if it is comma sperate  value, you may use split method.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server family, you can use a query similar to this  :

```
declare @tmpTable as table (test varchar(50))


insert into @tmpTable
select 'val' Go 100
```

now you can use @tmpTable

Comment: I still hope there is a solution without declaring an additional table.

Comment: I understand that you want to reduce the cost of defining variables. This is an inexpensive method to use. Because after the end of the session, the variables will destroy automatically.

Comment: Please add your comment to the answer, it is a benefit for your solution. Unfortunately the DBMS of the question seems [tag:Postgresql]